# FQL using JavaScript? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, facebook-fql

Is it possible to use the FQL in JavaScript to query Facebook for information? If so, how would I do that? Anyone have an example of how to do use the FQL in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is specify FQL in the method:

```
FB.api({
  method: 'fql.query',
  query: 'FQL query goes here'
},function(response) {
  // callback code goes here
});
```